# stale closure in reactjs, why hooks are not called in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know why these results are coming out.
here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function Main() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  const onClosure = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`before = ${val}`);
      setVal(val + 1);
      console.log(`inside = ${val}`);
    }, 1000);
  };
  
  console.log(`outside = ${val}`);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{val}</div>

      <div>hi!!</div>
      <div>good</div>
      <button onClick={onClosure}>click me</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

In stale closure problems, when I clicked button many times very fast, always only 2 re-renders work, but inner statements which are in setTimeout() are called properly. I don`t know why. plz clarify this problem .. Thank you!!

this is my result img (I can`t understand):

[image: result.png]

Comment: You can pass a callback function to `setVal` which will pass the current state. `setVal(currVal => currVal + 1);`

Comment: thank you for reply. Yes, i can correct answer if i use your suggested code, but all I want to know is why the internal functions(console.log) work so well and the re-renders only happen twice

Comment: You are setting it to the same value (`1`) on every  tick so React doesn't rerender. The first two are possibly [`strict mode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) at work. the `inside` log will always match the `before` because the new value won't be available until the next render cycle. Also the `val` logged by `inside` and `before` are not the current `val` but a closure over the initial value (after the first tick `val` is 1 and doesn't change).

Comment: Thank you!! now i understand why that result comes out!! your answer helps a lot!!